# ¿Cómo seleccionar una fila de un Jtable y almacenarla en un archivo?

Tags: java, java-swing

¿Cómo podria seleccionar todos los elementos de una fila de un Jtable y almacenarlos en un nuevo archivo de texto por medio del evento MouseCliked?

hola buenas soy bastante novata en java, y estoy haciendo un programa donde manejo los archivos de texto al menos esta es mi primer ventana donde se visualizan por medio de un Jtable los datos que se ingresaron al primer archivo, entonces ahora lo que ocupo hacer es que por medio del evento MouseCliked seleccionar uno y almacenarlo en un nuevo archivo

pero sinceramente no me da la cabeza para pensar como podría hacer esto, osea tomar la seleccion y dividir cada string para luego almacenarlo en un nuevo archivo, ingresarlo es fácil porque ya lo hice y igual mostrarlo, pero ahora debo sacar el seleccionado y guardarlo en un nuevo archivo pero no se como podría hacer esto ? podrían darme una ayuda el evento mouseClick ya lo tengo pero nose como deberia hacer la logica para programar esto que les comento, **les agradeceria de antemano que me explicaran como podria manejar el Jtable, para al darle click a uno de estos elementos se guarden el id,nombre,primer apellido, segundo apellido, tipo de prestamo y la renta a pagar en un nuevo archivo al darle al boton agregar usuario**

**uso netbeans**

este es un poco el codigo que cree para hacer el recorrido y guardar en un arreglo todos los string de esa fila

```
 Object[] rowData = new Object[tabladatos.getColumnCount()];
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tabladatos.getColumnCount(); i++){
            
            rowData = (Object[]) tabladatos.getValueAt(tabladatos.getColumnCount(),i);
        }
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rowData);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un atributo de clase para que guarde el numero de fila al cual haces click en la tabla y cuando das click en el boton de guardar primero obtienes los valores de cada columna de la fila seleccionada.

Veamos el código.

```
public class TuClase extends javax.swing.JFrame  {
    private int seleccionFila;

    //obtenemos el número de fila seleccionada al dar click en la tabla
    private void tuTablaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        seleccionFila= tuTabla.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    } 

    // evento al dar click en el boton agregar usuario
    private void btnAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //creamos variable locales para obtener los valores de cada columna de la fila seleccionada       
        int id=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tuTabla.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 0)));
        String nombre=String.valueOf(tuTabla.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 1));
        String apellido1=String.valueOf(tuTabla.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 2));
        String apellido2=String.valueOf(tuTabla.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 3));
        String tipoPrestamo=String.valueOf(tuTabla.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 4));
        double renta=Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tuTabla.getValueAt(seleccionFila, 5)));
        /*
         Agregas el código para guardar en el archivo, según la descripción de tu problema 
         sabes como realizarlo
        */
    }

}
```

Comment: waw @Joshin encerio me ayudaste muchas gracias lo hacen parecen tan facil ustedes los cracks jajaja, te podria hacer una ultima consulta como ago para borrar el elemento seleccionado que ya se agrego al archivo de texto? estoy usando un modelo.removeRow(seleccionFila); pero no me funciona

Comment: @EstherPorta hace tiempo que no veo ficheros solo base de datos, pero la idea es la misma; 1) buscar en el fichero un elemento a eliminar para esto el elemento a buscar tiene que ser única y viendo tu tabla hay varias filas con los mismos datos, entonces es recomendable que cada linea añadido en tu fichero tenga un id único. 2) eliminar el elemento encontrado en el fichero. ¿No se si esto es lo que buscabas o quieres eliminar de la tabla el elemento seleccionado?

Comment: ok muchas gracias igualmente